# Harry Potter dark-colored phoenix fanfic

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Need help identifying a Harry Potter fanfic.

**Publish date:** Before 2010. Given the in-universe period, likely before HP5 or HP6 was published.

**Main plot detail remembered:** Harry became associated with a rare **dark** (I think "black" but not sure) Phoenix. Don't really remember much else about the plot though. Just to be clear - this was a REAL BIRD - not Harry's Animagus form or mascot/mark as most fics named "Dark Phoenix" seem to be about.

**Size:** Novel length. As in, 100+ KB size, at least.

**In-universe period covered:** I think it starts after year 4 or 5.

**Non-typical fic**: Normal narrative (as in, no deeply alternate universe differing from prior HP books, no parallel worlds, no time travel, no weird romantic pairings). It's a straight up sequel to the previous JKR book.

My Google-fu seems insufficient to find it - every one I found was some weird Alternate universe thing.

Comment: Do you remember which site you might have read it on? (Or conversely, which sites it definitely wasn’t on?)

Comment: @alexwlchan - it was actually compiled into an e-book, don't know which site it originated from.

Comment: http://www.fanfiction.net/s/2070225/ ??

Comment: @JohnP - sorry. This was about Harry's Animagus form being a Phoenix, not a real bird.

Comment: I was going through old bookmarks, and I found something called a **dark phoenix** or **Bennu feather** (this was in the context of wand cores). Does that ring any bells?

Comment: @alexwlchan - no, there was no mention of wand cores that I recall in the context of black phoenix.

Comment: You should feature questions more frequently here. And, the bounty should be big. What are you going to do with all those reputations, seriously?

Comment: @SachinShekhar:
:-P In some ways it's like the argument that billionaires should give everyone $100. They can afford it and they don't need all that money, right? But it does kind of saturate things.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for this?

https://archive.org/stream/FakeOrderOfThePheonix/Fake%20order%20of%20the%20pheonix#page/n12/mode/1up

It's a fake version of OotP that came out just before the real OotP did. At the time, some people thought it was a leaked version of the real OotP.

The black phoenixes in it are real animals, not animagus forms or anything.

Comment: This is a really good find, but from starting to read it, I have a feeling that it was not the fic I recall. I am pretty sure i'd remember Dudley and Harry watching Monty Python :)

Comment: I think this will have the bounty awarded since I wasn't able to find the fic on my own in the last week. But, for the record, that book is 100% certainly **NOT the fic I was looking for**. Among other things, resurrecting Lily and the fact that OotP is some antient order related to birds are definitely NOT what it contained.