# What HP fanfic involved (late in the story) muggle investigators becoming characters focused on and entering the magic world?

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Related to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44823/need-help-identifying-a-harry-potter-fanfic) question in that I too am looking for a HP fanfic.

I remember that late in it, it changed from being about HP or some new character to being about some muggle investigators.

Their computer screens were smashed to destroy the evidence, but of course it was still on the hard drive. Their minds were wiped, so the female recorded her discoveries on a little cassette.

Somehow they make their way into the magic world and exchange some money for gold.

And that is about where I stopped reading. Could have been from *Harry Potter and the Natural 20* or *Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality*, but I can't find it in there anywhere... trying to make sure it's the right one before I reread the entire thing.

Comment: No idea what it is, but interesting premise. Do you remember 1) when you read it, and 2) where you read it?

Comment: fanfiction.net I am assuming -- and about 2 years ago, maybe 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would indeed be [*Harry Potter and the Natural 20*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8096183/1/Harry-Potter-and-the-Natural-20). Fiona is the investigator in question. Is is introduced in [Chapter 36](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8096183/36/Harry-Potter-and-the-Natural-20), where she was the investigator on the scene when Milo went to break Harry out of the Dursley house. She shows up again in 38, dealing with the computer with the smashed monitor. And again in 40, she introduces the tape recorder. She does become more prominent in later parts, particularly after

> Milo is killed

but she still remains a side story, an indication of just how terrifying the Wizards can be to the Muggles, and correspondingly how the Wizards have good reason to fear the Muggles learning of them.

Comment: Damn, I hadn't seen a spoiler field look like that before. It looked too fat to be a pure formatting choice though, so I hovered. Damn! :o - but thanks for confirming it. EDIT: just came back to change the swear word from the start of the sentence, thought I used the F-word but didn't actually. Felt so much like the right word, that I thought I had used it.

Comment: I apologize for spoiling you. I was trying to be discreet about it, but it is a factor of why the storyline starts discussing Fiona more often.

Comment: No worries, now I know what spoiler bars look like on here.